# laravel relationship problems with pivot table

Tags: laravel, relationship

Im trying to solve this problem with relationships in the pivot table. i have 3 tables (products, collections, collection_product)

products table
id
name
size_id

collections table
id
name

collection_product table
id (I know... i must use attach and detach) but later i will figure it out how to solve it)
collection_id
product_id

**MODELS**

Product Model

```
public function collections()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Collection::class);
}
```

Collection Model

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'collection_product');
}
```

ProductCollection Pivot Table

```
class ProductCollection extends Pivot
{
    protected $table = 'collection_product';

    public function collections()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Collection::class, 'collection_id');

    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'product_id');
    }
}
```

and in my CollectionController i want to search one collection and for all the products shown in the collection i want to show in the blade view only the size "SMALL" (size_id) products but i dont know how to code it in my controller, because first i need to fix the relationships and then figure out how to declare a condition to take size_id of my products table.

Comment: side note: the relationships `collections` and `products` on `ProductCollection` would be `belongsTo` not `hasMany`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can eager load the products for the collection you want and constrain what it loads:

```
$col = Collection::with('products', fn ($q) => $q->where('size_id', ...))
     ->findOrFail(...);

@foreach ($col->products as $product)
   ...
@endforeach
```

You could also get all the products and filter them before iterating them:

```
$col = Collection::findOrFail(...);

@foreach ($col->products->where('size_id', ...) as $product)
    ...
@endforeach
```

Comment: Nice!! actually it works

$products = $collection->products->where('size_id', $sizeId->id);